# Trimming binary tree data c

Tags: c, time-complexity, binary-search-tree

I'm currently developing some methods to work with binary trees. This is the structure I'm using.

```
struct node {
    char entry[40];
    char translation[100];
    int views;
    bool marker;
    node* left;
    node* right;
};
```

When I submit the code I have to a platform that evaluates it, returning Accepted, Wrong Answer, Presentation Error, Runtime Error, Compile error, etc... I'm getting the Presentation Error.

According to the platform, when I load the words to the tree, I'm inserting them with some spaces at the beginning and at the end.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

struct node {
    char entry[40];
    char translation[100];
    int views;
    bool marker;
    node* left;
    node* right;
};


bool search(node* root, char entry[40], bool acrescenta);

node* createNode(char entry[40], char translation[40], int views, bool marker) {
    node* newNode = new node();
    strcpy(newNode->entry, entry);
    strcpy(newNode->translation, translation);
    newNode->views = 0;
    newNode->marker = false;
    newNode->left = newNode->right = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

node* insert(node* root, char entry[40], char translation[40], int views, bool marker, bool acrescenta) {

    if(search(root, entry, acrescenta)) {
        printf("PALAVRA JA EXISTENTE\n");
        return root;
        } else if(root == NULL && acrescenta) {
        root = createNode(entry, translation, views, marker);
        printf("PALAVRA ACRESCENTADA\n");
    } else if(root == NULL && !acrescenta) {
                root = createNode(entry, translation, views, marker);
    } else if(strcmp(entry, root->entry) < 0) {
                root->left = insert(root->left, entry, translation, views, marker, acrescenta);
    } else {
                root->right = insert(root->right, entry, translation, views, marker, acrescenta);
    }

    return root;
}


bool search(node* root, char entry[40], bool acrescenta) {

    if(root == NULL) return false;

    if((strcmp(entry, root->entry) == 0) && acrescenta) {
            return true;
    } else if(strcmp(entry, root->entry) == 0) {
                printf("%s %s\n", root->entry, root->translation);
                return true;
    } else if(strcmp(entry, root->entry) < 0) {
                return search(root->left, entry, acrescenta);
    } else {
                return search(root->right, entry, acrescenta);
    }
}


void markWord(node *root, char entry[40]){

    if(root == NULL) return;

    markWord(root->left, entry);
    if(strcmp(root->entry, entry) == 0) {
        root->marker = true;
        printf("%s MARCADA\n", root->entry);
    }
    markWord(root->right, entry);
}


void printTree(node* root){
    if(root == NULL) return;

    printTree(root->left);
    printf("%s\n", root->entry);
    printTree(root->right);
}


void printMarkedWords(node *root){
    if(root == NULL) return;

    printMarkedWords(root->left);
    if(root->marker == true) printf("%s\n", root->entry);
    printMarkedWords(root->right);
}

int main() {
    node* root = NULL;

    char option[20];
    char entry[40];
    char translation[100];
    char line[175];

        while(fgets(line, 175, stdin) != NULL && line[0] != '\n') {
        sscanf(line, "%s %s %[^\t\n]", option, entry, translation);

        if(strcmp(option, "CARREGA") == 0) {
            while(1) {
                fgets(line, 175, stdin);
                line[strlen(line) - 1] = '\0';
                if(strcmp(line, "fim$dicionario") == 0) {
                    printf("DICIONARIO CARREGADO\n");
                    break;
                } else {
                    sscanf(line, "%s %[^\t\n]", entry, translation);
                    root = insert(root, entry, translation, 0, false, false);
                }
            }
        } else if(strcmp(option, "PESQUISA") == 0) {
            if(!search(root, entry, false)) printf("PALAVRA NAO EXISTENTE\n");
        } else if(strcmp(option, "ACRESCENTA") == 0) {
            root = insert(root, entry, translation, 0, false, true);
        } else if(strcmp(option, "MARCA") == 0) {
            if(!search(root, entry, true)) printf("PALAVRA NAO EXISTENTE\n");
            else (markWord(root, entry));
        } else if(strcmp(option, "LISTA_MARCADAS") == 0) {
            printMarkedWords(root);
            printf("FIM MARCADAS\n");
        } else if(strcmp(option, "LISTA_ALFANUM") == 0) {
            printTree(root);
            printf("FIM LISTA\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It seems that I got it right, but for some reason, some random spaces at the beginning of my data (entry and translation) are giving me the Presentation Error. Sorry if my explanation is not the most correct, but didn't want to make a long unreadable post.

Thanks :)

Comment: You're scanning the input in several places, so `printf` what you've scanned in each place, and then you'll know where you're going wrong.

Comment: How do you know that your problem is random spaces at the beginning of your outputs?   You've not shown `createNode()` or a couple of other functions, nor any test data with expected vs actual output, so we can't easily identify where the trouble is.  I'm not confident in making the guess, but what you've shown looks reasonable, so I suspect that `createNode()` is mishandling something.

Comment: The teacher who has access to the platform answers, tells me that when I'm inserting entry and translation to the tree I'm adding some extra spaces and that I should use a trim function everytime I want to insert. I've done printf in multiple places and just can't seem to find where those spaces are coming from. @JonathanLeffler edited the original code with the createNode() function.

Comment: The `createNode()` function looks clean.  It's not clear what might be causing trouble.  Could the lines have trailing spaces?  You're filtering on 'not a tab, not a newline' which allows spaces.  If so, you simply need to look at the translation string and strip trailing blanks.  Could it be that there are multiple spaces between words in the translation and you're supposed to replace each sequence of one or more spaces with a single space?  Read the specification again in detail.  Look at the sample data carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the platform input that was adding some spaces to the words, so I had to take care of it with some simple trim functions.

Thanks everyone who took time of their day to help me.